# HTTP Put request throws unexpected token error

Tags: angular, http, syntax-error, put

I am using Angular 6 and Spring boot. I am making a HTTP PUT request to server, which sends response as test(i.e. ResponseEntity<'some message', HttpStatus.OK>. My put request looks as `this.http.put(this.url + 'clients/' + id, { responseType: 'text' });`. When I make this request, I get parsing error saying 'unexpected token at position'. This exact same request works if it is a delete request. I am not able to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Is it an error coming from your API or a JS error? Could you please provide the whole error message?

Comment: I think `put` request needs at least 2 arguments. The first one is `url` which you have, the second one is body which you don't have. Instead of body you pass request options that must be after body as the third argument

Comment: @epsilon right on point. That was the issue. Thank you

Comment: @Michael as explained by epsilon it put request requires body argument which I didn't have and that was causing an issue as it considered request options as body and parse that as JSON, leaving the request expecting a JSON response and not text.

For your reference, the exact error was: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 3 at JSON.parse`